# How to implement a better custom Diailog form

Tags: java, android

I am developing a calendar app and want to display an add event form on a modal container shown [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2wp7IN_lTtleUR2SFFiUWJZekk/view?usp=sharing). I have tried to create a custom dialog box but it does do what i want ([here is a snapshot of my current dialog box](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2wp7IN_lTtlRzM4ZF8yWUVXRms/view?usp=sharing)), which is for the width of the container to cover 90% of my screen. Is their anyway i can adjust the size of the dialog box or use any other suitable container, thanks in advance.

here is my custom dialog box code

```
public class QuickAddEventDialogBox extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener{

private Context context;
private Button save, discard;

public QuickAddEventDialogBox(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.quick_add_event_dialogbox);


    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
    discard = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_discard);

    save.setOnClickListener(this);
    discard.setOnClickListener(this);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the window and call `setLayout(width, height)` to it. Something like so:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.quick_add_event_dialogbox);

    //set layout here  
    this.getWindow().setLayout(600, 400);

    ...

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try in the layout of the dialog box to use a **LinearLayout** and use weights?

Have your **LinearLayout** match_parent size and inside have a child (The dialog view) with weight of 0.9 (weightSum of 1) and use gravity="center" or layout_gravity="center"

Read about **LinearLayout** here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

Here is an example:

[How to make layout to be 80% of the width of the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818140/how-to-make-layout-to-be-80-of-the-width-of-the-screen)

I believe this will solve your question in the most elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the dialog size with:

```
getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(w,h);
```

If you want 90% width:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(display.getHeight() * 0.9, 
    display.getWidth() *x [or wrap_content]);
```

Also someone suggested to use weights, thats a good idea.